# reasoning behind typeof('apple') vs typeof 'apple'

Tags: javascript

Just poking around looking at areas I usually gloss over, and noticed this.

```
typeof('apple'); //"string"

typeof 'apple'; //"string"
```

Ok so first, how does that second example work? I get the first one is a function and parameter. Is the second one an operator that just happens to have the same name as the function? Whats going on there?

Second question : Why do it this way? Can I define my functions without using ()?

Comment: `typeof` is an operator, not a function. The parentheses are as meaningless as in `x = (1 + 2);`

Comment: [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is an operator, not a function. You don't need the brackets, they are being ignored. Compare `var a = 1` with `var a = (1)`.

Comment: If only there weren't this bad nerving in people's fingers… everyone just utterly loves to add superfluous parenthesizing all over the place, especially around the operand of prefix unary operators. Please no!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is based on the assumption that `typeof` is a function. It is not! `typeof` is an [**unary operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), just like `-`, `+`, `~`, or `!`.

> Whats going on there?

This expression

```
typeof('apple')
```

is *not* a function call, it is the `typeof` operator followed by a parenthesized expression. It the same as writing `!(foo)` instead of `!foo`.

> Why do it this way?

If you saw code like that it's either to make some precedence clearer or the person who wrote the code didn't know better.

> Can I define my functions without using ()?

Defining functions and calling functions are two different things. I assume you mean the latter and the answer is *no*. However, constructor functions can be called without `()` if you don't pass arguments. I.e. `new Foo` is the same as `new Foo()`.

Comment: @AJPerez: It's both, there is a [unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B)).

Comment: Oh. You're right. Never heard of that one before... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

The typeof **operator** returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.

> The typeof operator is followed by its operand:
>
> typeof operand

```
// Strings
typeof "" === 'string';
typeof "bla" === 'string';
typeof (typeof 1) === 'string'; // typeof always return a string
typeof String("abc") === 'string'; // but never use this form!
```